# Embed Haskell in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, haskell

I am writing a Node.js service that uses various utilities from the Node ecosystem, but the core part of the logic needs to generate a JavaScript AST (ESTree) from some given JSON configuration. It will also include reading various JS files and combining them if required. I am designing the code generation part by defining a domain specific grammar.

The Haskell code will return a ESTree AST which Node.js will convert to JS code using some existing utility.

I am looking for a good way to call Haskell code from Node.js to achieve this.

Comment: Compile using GHCJS?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html ?

Comment: https://github.com/nh2/call-haskell-from-anything